# How to replace the hash tag except in color code string

Tags: jquery

```
 $(this).html($(this).html().replace( /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<a class="hashtag" href="' + SP_source() + '?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>'
```

I have tried the above it is replacing all hash including in the style 
I need help to replace all hash without replacing the color code

Current result:

```
#808000;">fvfvfvfvfvfvfvf
```

expected results;
`fvfvfvfvfvfvfvf` (with applied color)

code:

```
<p>
  <span style="color: <a class=" hashtag"="" href="http://owos.lan/?hashtag=808000">
    #808000;"&gt;
    <em><strong>fvfvfvfvfvfvfvf #trends #trend2</strong></em>
  </span>
</p>
```

html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p><span style="font-size: 18pt;">svzvzgv #trends #trends2</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

code in js

```
 $('.text-wrapper').each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace( /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<a class="hashtag" href="' + SP_source() + '?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>'
            ));
        });
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code to fully understand its context. What is `this`? What does its HTML look like?

Comment: Your HTML has some obvious syntax issues, which you can see in the syntax highlighter of the example. That seems to be the cause of your issue. We still need to see a more useful sample of your JS, though

Comment: I am using tiny mce editor for showing hashtag follwed by name 
I am replacing the hashtag name to link 
When i am applying style to the text say color:#fffff  so it replace to link
i need the solution to replace all the hash tag except the color code

Comment: Sorry, that makes little to no sense. Again, we need to see ***much*** more of your code which is causing this problem.

Comment: i have updated the code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the using a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace( /#([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})(?![a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, '<a class="hashtag" href="' + SP_source() + '?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>')
```

This should also take care of your short color codes with 3 characters. If you want to keep only 6 char codes, use this

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace( /#([a-fA-F0-9]{6})(?![a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, '<a class="hashtag" href="' + SP_source() + '?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>')
```

Comment: Why? Isn't that your best answer yet?